# Do the ReportViewer components of Visual Studio 2010 correspond to SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 or 2008 R2?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, reportviewer, rdlc

See title. Basically, I'd like to know whether the bug fixes introduced with R2 are also contained in the Visual Studio 2010 local reporting components or not.

Comment: I think they're different things: the reporting components are based on Crystal Reports whereas the SSRS is something else. Certainly the SSRS visual studio support is completely separate. But I've never used the reporting components myself.

Comment: @Rup: Visual Studio contains two types of reporting components: (a) "Microsoft Reporting Technology" (ReportViewer, RDLC) which use the "local reports" engine of SSRS, and (b) Crystal Reports. Both are included in Visual Studio. My question is about (a). I know that the reporting components of VS2008 correspond to SSRS2005, but I'm not sure about VS2010, hence my question.

Comment: Ah, thanks - didn't know it had both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about specific bug fixes but I would expect not.

Visual Studio 2010 (or more accurately ReportViewer 10.0) supports only the RDL 2008 schema in Local processing mode.

The new RDL 2010 schema was introduced alongside SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 R2.  Since Visual Studio 2010 has not yet been updated to handle this schema it's unlikely that the engine includes R2 bug fixes.

[Version summary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207009%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Amazing that we're at VS2015 and still only the 2008 is supported. There is a mistake in the linked version of the article. It says 2010 RDL is supported. Other SQL Server versions of the article are correct.